# Does my kitchen sink trap have a removable cap?

Tags: plumbing, drain

My condo in Toronto was built in 2013. Does my kitchen's trap have the "removable cap" mentioned in [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/96914/do-you-really-need-a-p-trap-on-bathroom-sinks?answertab=oldest#comment142085_96914)?

[Full resolution image](https://i.ibb.co/Mcc3f1Y/p-trap.jpg)

[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHiEp.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't have a drain cap. You can remove the entire trap by loosening the trap union and the tailpiece adapter. You will probably spill stinky water. That's what the drain on traps is for. So clear out under sink and get wide short container to catch dirty water.